# How to remove RVM after renaming directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, terminal, rvm

I renamed my directory in the finder after installing RVM.  Then I created a rails app and tried to run the server in terminal but got the following error that runs on a loop.

```
ruby-2.0.0-p353 - #gemset created /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0
mkdir: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin: Permission denied
ln: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/cache: No such file or directory
```

I looked around and think it's RVM and so I ran

```
rm -rf /.rvm
```

And:

```
rvm implode
```

But returned the following error:

```
Could not remove '/usr/local/rvm/', please try removing it manually.
```

I couldn't find it and/or didn't know where to look...

I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me restore my environment/paths by providing step by step (very granual please, I'm new at this) and/or uninstall RVM if that is in fact the problem.

Comment: you probably installed `rvm` as root user so you want to run `sudo rvm implode` and install `rvm` as a non-root user

Answer (score 1):

you may need to run `sudo rvm implode`

Answer (score 0):

You can determine where your rvm is installed by running `rvm info`

Remove the `'/usr/local/rvm/'` using sudo, so `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/rvm`

Have a look at this site, which suggest how to completely remove rvm.

http://mkoby.com/2011/06/03/completely-removing-rvm/